# Pydantic - How to subclass a builtin type

Tags: python, subclass, built-in, pydantic

I'm trying to make a subclass of timedelta that expects to receive milliseconds instead of seconds, but it's not currently working.

Am I going against the grain? Is there a "right" way to achieve this with Pydantic? Or do I somehow need to tell Pydantic that `MillisecondTimedelta` is just a `timedelta`..

```py
from datetime import timedelta

from pydantic import BaseModel


class MillisecondTimedelta(timedelta):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        # timedelta expects seconds
        yield lambda v: v / 1000
        yield cls


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    td: MillisecondTimedelta

data = {
    "td": 7598040,
}

print(MyModel(**data))
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    class MyModel(BaseModel):
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 262, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 315, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 284, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 362, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 541, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.populate_validators
  File "pydantic/class_validators.py", line 255, in pydantic.class_validators.prep_validators
  File "pydantic/class_validators.py", line 238, in pydantic.class_validators.make_generic_validator
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 3105, in signature
    return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 2854, in from_callable
    return _signature_from_callable(obj, sigcls=cls,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 2384, in _signature_from_callable
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: no signature found for builtin type <class '__main__.MillisecondTimedelta'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, turns out I needed to change 2 things.

1. Actually return a `timedelta` from the validator, I was returning `cls` which was my custom subclass.
2. Don't subclass `timedelta`

```py
from datetime import timedelta

from pydantic import BaseModel


class MillisecondTimedelta:

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield lambda v: timedelta(milliseconds=v)


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    td: MillisecondTimedelta


data = {
    "td": 7598040,
}

print(repr(MyModel(**data)))
```

```
MyModel(td=datetime.timedelta(seconds=7598, microseconds=40000))
```

Answer (score 2):

As shown [on the doc page of `__get_validators__()`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#custom-data-types), you need to yield one or more validators.

The modified class is reported below; the problem was that Pydantic understands (for a timedelta field) int and floats as seconds [(source)](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#datetime-types).

```py
class MillisecondTimedelta(timedelta):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if any(isinstance(v, t) for t in (int, float)):
            return cls(milliseconds=v)
```

Now everything should work correctly.

```py
>>> data = {"td": 1000}
>>> print(MyModel(**data))
td=MillisecondTimedelta(seconds=1)
```

EDIT: Without a custom class and a validator, it's possible to use a function to edit the value to assign to the class constructor; it's required to decorate this function, [as seen here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/)

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    td: timedelta

    @validator('td')
    def convert_to_ms(cls, v):
        return v / 1000
```

Also this solution is working:

```py
>>> data = {"td": 3000}
>>> print(MyModel(**data))
td=datetime.timedelta(seconds=3)
```

Comment: Aha, so you're instantiating a `timedelta` in the validator and returning that. I thought that I would be able to just modify the value, and then defer to the default behaviour of `timedelta`. Is it not possible to subclass a type and add a validation step before the normal validation?

Comment: Also, is it possible to make the resulting object be a simple `datetime.timedelta` rather than a `MillisecondTimedelta`?.. I think that's what `__origin__` is for..

Comment: Check edit, I think this is the intended behaviour you had in mind

Comment: Thanks, the intention of creating the custom field was to avoid having to add the validator to every model and field that represents a `timedelta`. Encapsulating it in the type seemed a lot neater. Seems like that may not be possible though..

Comment: You can reuse the function used (check last link in the edit), but I think that it stops there; you can either use a subclass instead of timedelta, or use a custom validator for the field in the model